# global variables typescript not defined

Tags: angular, facebook, typescript, facebook-graph-api, ionic-framework

I have a problem with typescript global variable.

I'm writing a piece of code to login with facebook in my ionic 3 app.

I have a global variable declared, but when the app runs, got me the error *.*FB is not defined** at the function **FB.init({})**

The code:

```
//all needed imports

declare const FB;

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationProvider implements OnInit{

  //properties

  //constructor

   ngOnInit() {
     debugger
     if( FB != null && FB != 'undefined')
     {
       FB.init({
         appId: '***',
         cookie: false,access
         status: true,
         xfbml: true,
         version: 'v2.11'
       });
     }
   }

   //FB.login(){} inside an observable function
   //FB.getLoginStatus(){} inside an observable function
   //FB.api(){} inside an observable function

 }
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: what is FB? you have declared as a global variable. Is it a cordova plugin? Are you sure it is loaded?

Comment: @SurajRao I've found a guide and I don't understand very well why the guy use this declaration. In development there are no erros. Only in production I've this error **FB is not defined**.

Answer (score 0):

In TypeScript const is a block scoped variable. For a true global variable you need to use var.

Comment: I've tried also with **declare var FB: any;** but without success. App get me same error **FB is not defined** .

Comment: Well and what is FB? From what I can see it’s neither null or undefined because it get’s inside the if. Maybe something wrong with your initialisation?

Answer (score -1):

Your FB api has not been correctly imported in your application.

this must be something similar as

`import * as FB from 'fb_api';`